# Logging into an App after authentication of phone number

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I have created an app that handles the authentication of phone numbers using firebase. Now I have another button called "Log in", I want this button to check if the any inputted phone-number is in registered in firebase and if its there I want it to go to the next screen(an intent) but if its not registered yet it should display unregistered phone number.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend you read through [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your questions should reflect coding steps you've taken with a specific detailed problem, so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In firebase, each registered phone number will have a unique id. So if a user login multiple time or from multiple devices he/she will get the same id. With this, you can check wheater the user is already registered or not.
You can use functions like docRef.isExists(), were docRef is your document reference.

Hope this help!